# How to create expand css3 animation like it's on HTC ONE M8 design slide

Tags: css, animation

I want some help regarding an CSS3 animation which is the mobile parts expand view on HTC ONE M8 website in the second "DESIGN" slide.

http://www.htc.com/us/smartphones/htc-one-m8/

Many Thanks Anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code? You could try some sort of horizontal transition where each element has a 3d skew on it. That would be a css3 animation whereas the transition is merely a css transition.